# Validate Ebay login credetials via API?

Tags: python, ebay-api

How do I use the Ebay API to validate login credentials?

I need to check if a login is valid or not, how to I do this via API?

I do have a developer Key e.g.

Comment: your question is unclear. are you talking about check if you have authorisation to perform actions on the user's behalf?

Comment: you do not actually get access to the users login creds.  I believe you are looking for auth token info no?  [link] http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/howto/tokens/gettingtokens.html